# Eigen 3.3.x: How to lamba-operate across all rows?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Suppose I have the following loop:

```
struct Obj {
   RowVectorXf payload;
   Obj(RowvectorXf payload) : payload(std::move(payload)) {};
}

MatrixXd data = ...

std::vector<Obj> payloads;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  payloads.emplace_back(data.row(i)(seq(1,10,2));
}
```

This is a simplification of my use case, which absolutely does need to step out into the `std::` space with a `struct` containing a slice for sanity and ease of coding.  Anyhow, I have started using the `unaryExpr`'s with abandon, and I am curious if there is something like a `rowExpr` that could perform this function without the for loop (and thus eliminating the visual noise).

```
// Goal, in pseudo code: 
data.rowExpr([](RowVectorXd row) payloads.emplace_back(row(seq(1,10,2));
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are really asking for here. Please clarify.

Comment: @RemyLebeau added pseudo-code.

Comment: Seems like you just need to implement a custom `iterator` for your `data` class to iterate through its `rows`, and then you can use `std::for_each()`, eg: `std::for_each(data.rows_begin(), data.rows_end(), [](RowVectorXd &row){ payloads.emplace_back(row(seq(1,10,2))); });`  or `std::for_each_n()`, eg: `std::for_each_n(data.rows_begin(), data.num_rows(), [](RowVectorXd &row){ payloads.emplace_back(row(seq(1,10,2))); });` I don't really see much benefit to eliminating the original `for` loop, though.

Comment: What does `data.row()` actually return? If it a pointer/reference to an element in a contiguous array, then you can use simple pointers as the iterators passed to `std::for_each/_n()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau looks like there is a version of what I am going for.  And, as to the above, I'd rather not -- that is the point.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but I really appreciate the advice!!

Comment: @RemyLebeau is there much benefit to differential notation? Not until you are doing a lot of differentials and variable separation. Bitwise notation? Same. These atomic operations have to conform to a certain style, otherwise they impair the effectiveness of the user -- like a pair of shoes you have to tie every step.  So these little insights are important.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @RemyLebeau Leibniz notation gives you separation of variables and easy pattern recognition in differential equations. Organizing mathematical moves by operators (which is what the leibniz notation is) that are nonetheless similar to simpler operations (like division, in this particular case) is the essence of math.  It is how you simplify the complex. Anyways, operators were an important invention, and they are a very useful syntactical tool.

Comment: (head spinning) sorry I asked...

Comment: @RemyLebeau ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the development branch of Eigen (and the upcoming 3.4 version) you can access the elements of Eigen objects using `std`-compatible iterators. To iterate row-wise through an Eigen expression, you need to write `data.rowwise().begin()` and `data.rowwise().end()` -- (to iterate column-wise, you need to write `.colwise().begin()` of course). And you can directly pass these to the constructor of `std::vector` (if the types are compatible).

Since in your example you also need to convert between `double` and `float` you can write something like this:

```
auto const& data_ = data.cast<float>().rowwise();
std::vector<Obj> payloads(data_.begin(), data_.end());
```

Full working example: https://godbolt.org/z/2x2jFJ